# AWS Secrets Rotation Lambda ignoring exceptions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

#### Is there a way to stop further execution of steps within the rotation function once an exception has been thrown?

**For Context:**

After following guidance provided by AWS ([documentation here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py)) I have created a custom lambda function in python to rotate secrets for an application hosted within an ec2 instance. I can get everything working within all 4 steps to rotate the secret successfully. However while testing I've noticed that anytime an exception is thrown, the steps continue to execute until the rotation completes.

For example, an error is raised in the "Set Secret" stage, but continues to execute "Test Secret" and "Finish Secret" step. I expected that where an exception occurs, the code would not be able to continue past this point. (Even though I know the rotation functionality is to execute the function several times upon failure.)

I hope this question makes sense!

Comment: Is your function exact copy of this? Please don't post links to code, or images of code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Now, the code that they provided, each method has a try-catch block of it's own, so it wouldn't stop other steps from executing.  If you would want to stop other steps, you'd need to modify it so that they are all part of the same try-catch block.